# How to check if a token is already added in Metamask?

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I have already read this previous answer [MetaMask API - How to detect if token already registered?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107253/metamask-api-how-to-detect-if-token-already-registered) however since it's quite old I was wondering if anyone else has fund a new solution to the following issue:

Upon clicking a button I use the following

```
    async function addTokenToWallet() {
    try {
      const wasAdded = await ethereum
      .request({
        method: "wallet_watchAsset",
        params: {
          type: "ERC20",
          options: {
            address: 'example contract address 0x...',
            symbol: 'EXP',
            decimals: 18,
            image: "https://example.com/favicon.ico",
          },
        },
      }).then((results) => {console.log('Token added successfully:', results)})
      .catch((error)=>{console.log(error)});

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

However the "wallet_watchAsset" will always prompt the pop up windown anytime it started.

Is there anyway to check before adding the token (when the user is already connected) if the token is already added in Metamask without opening the prompt/pop window?

Anyone found a good solution for this?
I was thinking about possible cookies solutions but they have some inherited issues and challenges on their own.

Anyone found a good solution?